# How to add an enode with Ubuntu and Parity UI?

Tags: parity, synchronization, ubuntu, enode

I have a problem of parity syncing and some one suggest me to use an enode as follows :

```
enode://147573f46fe9f5cc38fbe070089a31390baec5dd2827c8f2ef168833e4d0254fbee3969a02c5b9910ea5d5b23d86a6ed5eabcda17cc12007b7d9178b6c697aa5@37.120.168.56:30303
```

The question is how to use this node ? I work with Ubuntu. Is there any specific command for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Parity UI, in the Node health Dapp (Home>Node health) you can click on the cogwheel and add any enode to your peers.
[image: parity add enode peer]

In the command line, you could use the flag `--reserved-peers`

`--reserved-peers=[FILE]
        Provide a file containing enodes, one per line. These nodes will always
        have a reserved slot on top of the normal maximum peers.`